# post method in express on other other router

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, middleware

how can i make a post request from a router, it works on the "/" pages but not working on the "/forget" page. when i replace "/forget" page to "/" pages it works fine but when the post method is from "/forget" it give error. here is my code 
please help look at it 
thanks in advance

this is my "/" pages it works fine here

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/activate', function(req, res) {
  var register = {
    Email: req.body.emial,
    Password: req.body.password,
    C_password: req.body.c_password    
}

var newUser = {
  Referer_mail : req.body.ref_email,
  Name : req.body.name,
  Country : req.body.country,
  Phone: req.body.phone,
  Email: req.body.emial,
  Wallet : 0 , 
  Invest : 0 ,
  Interest : 0 ,
  Income : 0,
  referal : 0 
}
if (register.Password === register.C_password){

  
  firebase.registerWithEmail(register.Email, register.Password, newUser,  function(err, result){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
      Message = err.message;
    }else {

      // send emial verification 
      firebase.sendVerificationEmail(result.token, function(err, result){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            Message = err.message;
        }else {
            console.log(result);
            
        }
    });


    // save name in data base 
    firebase.database().ref("Profile").child(result.user.id).set({newUser}, function (err, result){
      if (err){
        console.log(err);
        Message = err.message;
        } else {
           console.log(result);
        }
      }) 
            
    console.log(result);
  }
      
  }); 

  res.render('pages/activate', {
    value : Message
  });
} else {
  console.log("password and confrim password not equal");
  res.render('pages/index', {
    value : " Your Password and Confrim Password are not equal"
  });
}

  
});
```

while this is my "/forget" pages give error

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/activate', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages/activate', {
    value : Message
  });
  
});
```

please help me find time and look at it, 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please make the code more minimal in the question. Isolate the problem.

Comment: i have done that pls

Comment: Where are you including the routes?

Comment: see it now, have include it

Comment: No you didn't. I don't think you know how routes work, go read the friend manual: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: Thanks man, can u pls send me a sample code, so that I can find my way out

Comment: Thanks man, could u pls send me a sample code, so that I can find my way out